# Is it possible to restore the encoding to a modified STDIN?

Tags: perl, encoding, stdin

Is it possible to restore the original encoding of STDIN, which encoding was previously modified?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

binmode STDIN, ':raw';

# do something here
# ...
# ...

# restore original STDIN encoding
binmode STDIN, $old_encoding;
```

Comment: Not really. For starters, each layer can have a buffer, so you could actually lose data by temporarily removing layers Do the encoding yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work, but there is the [`:pop` pseudo-encoding](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PerlIO#%3apop) that:

> removes the top-most layer. Gives perl code a way to manipulate the layer stack. Should be considered as experimental. Note that :pop only works on real layers and will not undo the effects of pseudo layers like :utf8. An example of a possible use might be:

```
open($fh,...)
...
binmode($fh,":encoding(...)");  # next chunk is encoded
...
binmode($fh,":pop");            # back to un-encoded
```

> A more elegant (and safer) interface is needed.